# Seeking Advice on Optimal Computer Configuration for Machine/Deep Learning: CPU, GPU, and VRAM Considerations

Tags: pc

I'm diving into the exciting world of machine and deep learning, and I could really use your expertise. I'm in the process of putting together a computer configuration that's tailor-made for these tasks. Here's what I've got on my list:

```
CPU: Ryzen 5600x
Motherboard: B450
RAM: 32GB DDR4 3200MHz
Storage: 1TB Gen 3 M.2 NVMe
GPU: RTX 4060Ti 16GB
Power Supply Unit: 750W
```

Now, I want to make sure my CPU and GPU work together like a dream for all those heavy-duty machine and deep learning tasks. That's why I'm splurging most of my budget on the GPU. The RTX 4060Ti caught my eye because it boasts a generous amount of VRAM. And we all know how crucial that is when you're dealing with massive datasets and complex neural networks. More VRAM means smoother training and inference, baby!

**Also I am a bit confused too because 4060ti has only 128 bit bus and 288 GB/s Bandwidth which is quite less ,even less than a 3060 12GB, therefore I was also thinking if this will create a bottleneck and should i just but a 3060 12gb instead.
By the way 4060ti is already bottleneck by bandwidths in DaVinci Resolve and other few productivity applications.**

DISCLAIMER I know the official performance details for the RTX 4060Ti aren't out yet since it's hitting the market in July. But if it turns out to be a dud, I might scramble to scrape together enough cash for the RTX 4070. It won't be easy, but I'll give it a shot.

On a side note I am seeking answers and advice regarding the optimal computer configuration for machine/deep learning tasks. Specifically, I want to determine if the chosen CPU and GPU combination (Ryzen 5600x and RTX 4060Ti 16GB) is suitable for these demanding tasks. I am also considering the importance of VRAM capacity in the GPU for handling large datasets and complex neural networks.